# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized (Podbean)

Tags: python, json, django

I am making a Django app to upload my .mp3 files in Podbean. I have tried uploading the file through 'terminal' and it was a success. But now I want to upload the files through my app. To achieve this I have to follow 3 steps. First I have to authorize the file through requests.post and get the result in json. Then from the json data I want to specifically get some data. I have tried the following query but an error shows up. If the first step will be achieved then I can easily do the other steps.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import os, json
import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 2

def upload_recordings(request):
    file_name = "/slayer.mp3"
    file_size = 1291021
    file_path = "path"
    title = "recording1"
    access_token = "1234567890"

    url = "https://api.podbean.com/v1/files/uploadAuthorize"
    data = {'access_token': access_token, 'filename': file_name, 'filesize': file_size}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'audio/mpeg'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    print(j)
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
send: 'POST /v1/files/uploadAuthorize HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.podbean.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.18.3\r\nContent-type: audio/mpeg\r\nContent-Length: 108\r\n\r\n{"access_token": "1234567890", "filesize": 1291021, "filename": "/slayer.mp3"}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n'
header: Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Date: Sat, 05 Aug 2017 02:05:00 GMT
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 Version 6.0 SSL TLS AntiSpam Mozilla 4.0 OS3
header: Set-Cookie: AWSELB=830BDD2714C96857D7F5E2533BF21492F4232C62646AC64AC5598D0BC21EBA8E9430BBD3332436913229AF2BA0BC6C26AA4E11A7088C5B56673E72BAACABF3FBFB98B00339;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=600
header: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service"
header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
header: Content-Length: 2
header: Connection: keep-alive
('-------------j', [])
```

Comment: Please show how you got it working from the command line. Either you're using something that was already authorized with the service, or the access token changes with each file uploaded.

Comment: No the access token doesnot change with every file upload. `curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/files/uploadAuthorize \
-G -d 'access_token={access_token}' -d 'filename=abc.mp3' -d 'filesize=1291021' -d 'content_type=audio/mpeg'`

Comment: https://developers.podbean.com/podbean-api-docs/#api-_footer here is the api documentation. You can scroll down to "Appendix" for full detail

Comment: I just ran the curl code in terminal and it gave me the required output: `{"presigned_url":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/a1.podbean.com\/tmp6\/1942938\/slayer.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJP2BVTWVJMFYIRCA&Expires=1501900057&Signature=6g0ad%2BNdDBZkJPogtgvkZDn2daE%3D","expire_at":600,"file_key":"tmp6\/1942938\/slayer.mp3"}`